# Vector finding midpount of CD

Tags: vector-spaces

The position vectors of points A and B relative to an origin O are a and b respectively. The position vectors of points C and D relative to O are 3a and 2b respectively. It is given that

[image: Vector A & B]

(i) Find the unit vector in the direction of CD. [3] 
(ii) The point E is the mid-point of CD. Find angle EOD. [6]

For part(i) i get correctly get 1/7(2,-3,6) 
 and part(ii) can't figured out how to find the midpoint ??

Comment: One way is to note that to 'get' to $b$ from $a$, you add $b-a$. So to get half-way, you add ${1 \over 2} (b-a)$. So, the midpoint is given by $a+ {1 \over 2} (b-a) = {1 \over 2} (a+b)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

If $A=(x_A,y_A,z_A)$ and $B=(x_B,y_B,z_B)$  are two points then their midpoint $I$ is

$$I=\left(\frac{x_A+x_B}{2},\frac{y_A+y_B}{2},\frac{z_A+z_B}{2}\right)$$